# Classify input numbers into fixed ranges, several million of times

Tags: python

I have a few ranges (that can overlap) as parameter; for example:

```py
# tuple[0] <= n < tuple[1]

ranges = [(70, 80), (80, 120), (120, 130), (120, 2000), (1990, 2000), (2000, 2040), (2040, 2050)]
```

And I have a list of tuples as input, where the second element of each tuple is the number that determines the range(s) the tuple belongs.

```py
tuples = [('a', 71), ('b', 79), ('c', 82), ('d', 121), ('e', 1991), ('f', 2010), ('g', 2045), ('h', 3000)]
```

I need to determine the members of each range and store the results in the following manner:

```py
# ranges[i] => members[i]

members = [{71: 'a', 79: 'b'}, {82: 'c'}, {121: 'd'}, {121: 'd', 1991: 'e'}, {1991: 'e'}, {2010: 'f'}, {2045: 'g'}]
```

My approach is to create a `dict` that associates a number to the range(s) it belongs:

```py
members = [{} for _ in ranges]
number_to_members = defaultdict(list)

for i,(x0,x1) in enumerate(ranges):
    for x in range(x0,x1):
        number_to_members[x].append(members[i])

for c,n in tuples:
    if n in number_to_members:
        for m in number_to_members[n]:
            m[n] = c
```

Now the problem is that I need to classify tens of millions of different lists of tuples using the same ranges; the current implementation would require to generate `number_to_members` for each list of tuples, which is a lot of overhead. How do you work around that problem?

---

##### UPDATE

Adding an example of the actual problem:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
  
ranges = [(70, 80), (80, 120), (120, 130), (120, 2000), (1990, 2000), (2000, 2040), (2040, 2050)]

inputs = [
    [('a', 71), ('b', 79), ('c', 82), ('d', 121), ('e', 1991), ('f', 2010), ('g', 2045), ('h', 3000)],
    [('x', 75), ('y', 78), ('z', 1995)]
]

members = [{} for _ in ranges]
number_to_members = defaultdict(list)

for i,(x0,x1) in enumerate(ranges):
    for x in range(x0,x1):
        number_to_members[x].append(members[i])

for tuples in inputs:
    for c,n in tuples:
        if n in number_to_members:
            for m in number_to_members[n]:
                m[n] = c
    print(members)
```

output:

```py
[{71: 'a', 79: 'b'}, {82: 'c'}, {121: 'd'}, {121: 'd', 1991: 'e'}, {1991: 'e'}, {2010: 'f'}, {2045: 'g'}]
[{71: 'a', 79: 'b', 75: 'x', 78: 'y'}, {82: 'c'}, {121: 'd'}, {121: 'd', 1991: 'e', 1995: 'z'}, {1991: 'e', 1995: 'z'}, {2010: 'f'}, {2045: 'g'}]
```

Comment: How many ranges do you actually have, how small/large are their numbers, and how much do they overlap?

Comment: @KellyBundy Thank you for comments. My bad, I indeed, I need to generate a new `members` array for each list of tuples. The provided `ranges` reflect the real input (small overlaps, few ranges, a few thousand of elements in one of the ranges), but the list of tuples can be a lot bigger.

Comment: Then I'd say your solution is pretty much optimal already.

Comment: (Except of course you shouldn't recompute `number_to_members` "for each list of tuples" but only once.)

Comment: @KellyBundy That's right, but how how do I do that?

Comment: Ah, my bad, I see the issue now. 
 `number_to_members` must reference the new `members` elements...

Comment: I suggest you expand your example/code to actually have/handle multiple lists of tuples. Two would be enough.

Comment: Would also be good to know how many tuples the lists typically have. If it's several thousand, then computing `number_to_members` for each isn't that expensive, relatively. If it's just dozens, then it is. Though I think I see something better now, but would need to test with multiple lists.

Comment: The code in UPDATE isn't correct, right? Since the second `members` contains data not only from the second input list but also from the first.

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes, it is incorrect. I tried to show that I need the `members` list to build `number_to_members` dict.

Comment: Do you need the `members` lists for all the inputs in parallel, i.e., do you need to collect them? Or is it ok to compute each `members` list, process it (in your example you just print it), and then you don't need it anymore?

Comment: the `members` are disposable; once we get to the next iteration then they don't serve any purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the sizes you mentioned, your code in UPDATE seems speed-wise rather optimal already, as it takes time proportional to the size of your desired outputs.

It's just incorrect, since it accumulates the input list data instead of computing the `members` list for each input alone.

Since you said you don't need the `members` after each iteration anymore, you can fix the issue by simply clearing the dicts:

```
for tuples in inputs:
    ...
    print(members)
    for m in members:
        m.clear()
```

If you change your mind and do need the `members` lists later, you can make a copy before you clear:

```
members_lists = []
for tuples in inputs:
    ...
    print(members)
    copy = [m.copy() for m in members]
    members_lists.append(copy)
    for m in members:
        m.clear()
```

Comment: Nice +1. Is clearing a `dict` slower than creating a new `dict`?

Comment: @Fravadona By itself, creating a new one is faster. But then you'd also throw away the old one, right? Which involves clearing it anyway. So overall it would be a little slower than just clearing. And more importantly, that's all really missing the point. If you create new dicts, then you need to recompute the whole `number_to_members`, in order to reference the new dicts. By clearing the existing dicts, the existing `number_to_members` remains valid.

Comment: @Fravadona Alternatively, you could make `number_to_members` reference not the dicts directly but their indexes. Then you could create new dicts and `number_to_members` would also remain valid. But it would require an indirection during the filling of the dicts for every insertion, and I suspect it would be slower. (Inspired by Masklinn's answer)